# How to call a method (using this) in Javascript from a button?

Tags: javascript, button, methods

Calling a function from a button is easy in javascript:

```
b.onclick = f;
```

Calling a method from a button can also be done:

```
Myclass.prototype.m = function() {
    var t = this;
    b.onclick = t.f;
}
```

But we want to call a method of our class from a button through another function.  Is there any way to do this without passing in the original object?

Here is the code that does not work.  this.e is interpreted in the context of the button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
</body>
<script>
function A() {}
A.prototype.e = function() {
  console.log("bar");
}

A.prototype.f = function() {
  console.log("foo!");
  this.e();
}

A.prototype.g = function() {
  var b = document.createElement("button");
  b.innerHTML = "say foo!";
  b.onclick = this.f;
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(b);
}

var a = new A();
a.g();

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: try `b.onclick = this.f.bind(this)`

Comment: @danronmoon You answered right first, so if you want to move it below I'll mark yours right....

Comment: OK, sure.  Haven't done that in a while :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to change the context of the `this` keyword to your `a` instance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
</body>
<script>
function A() {}
A.prototype.e = function() {
  console.log("bar");
}

A.prototype.f = function() {
  console.log("foo!");
  this.e();
}

A.prototype.g = function() {
  var b = document.createElement("button");
  b.innerHTML = "say foo!";
  b.onclick = this.f.bind(this);
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(b);
}

var a = new A();
a.g();

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the flow interrupted you should bind the following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
</body>
<script>
function A() {}
A.prototype.e = function() {
  console.log("bar");
}

A.prototype.f = function() {
  console.log("foo!");
  this.e();
}

A.prototype.g = function() {
  var b = document.createElement("button");
  b.innerHTML = "say foo!";
  b.onclick = this.f.bind(this)
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(b);
}

var a = new A();
a.g();

</script>
</html>
```